# Chrome Extension - Use javascript to run periodically, and log data permanently

Tags: javascript, database, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Currently, I have a script that when the image in the top right tray is clicked(only for one specific allowed website), it scans the pages HTML then outputs some value. This scanning and outputting is a function in a single JS file, called say checkData.js.

Is it possible, even if a user is not actively using a tab but it is open, to automatically have the script run every 10 seconds and log data to some place I can access later within the extension? THis is because the pages HTML is constantly changing. The I suppose I would use alarms or event pages, but I am not sure how to integrate that.

Comment: The requirements are a bit .. unclear. What does 'scanning' do? How important is the write? Are the concerns about tampering (or changing/clearing the browser data)? Etc.

Comment: There is no tampering, the HTML is not changed. The scanning just does a document.firstChild and converts some data to string format. The whole point of the periodic checking is to write that string to a file periodically, as the HTML changes (every 10 seconds should be sufficient).

Answer (score 4):

Chrome limits the frequency of repeating alarms to at most once per minute. If that is OK, here is how to do it:

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36238221/4468645) on how to setup an event page.

In the background.js you would do something like this:

```
// event: called when extension is installed or updated or Chrome is updated
function onInstalled() {
    // CREATE ALARMS HERE
    ...
}

// event: called when Chrome first starts
function onStartup() {
    // CREATE ALARMS HERE
    ...
}

// event: alarm raised
function onAlarm(alarm) {
    switch (alarm.name) {
        case 'updatePhotos':
            // get the latest for the live photo streams
            photoSources.processDaily();
            break;
        ...
        default:
            break;
    }
}

// listen for extension install or update
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(onInstalled);

// listen for Chrome starting
chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(onStartup);

// listen for alarms
chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(onAlarm);
```

Creating a repeating alarm is done like this:

```
// create a daily alarm to update live photostreams
function _updateRepeatingAlarms() {
    // Add daily alarm to update 500px and flickr photos
    chrome.alarms.get('updatePhotos', function(alarm) {
        if (!alarm) {
            chrome.alarms.create('updatePhotos', {
                when: Date.now() + MSEC_IN_DAY,
                periodInMinutes: MIN_IN_DAY
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This is perfect! Would MIN_IN_DAY just be 1 for my case? And would onInstalled and onStartup just start the alarm? How do you do that?

Comment: @JoeBob Yes on the 1.  `onInstalled` and `onStartup` would just call a function like `_updateRepeatingAlarms`. The call to `chrome.alarms.create` starts the alarm automatically.

Comment: Great! And MSEC_IN_DAY would be 1000? How would photoSources.processDaily() post a string to the background page, and how is the background page info retrieved (say, in when the user clicks the icon in the tray?)

Comment: Just in case anyone finds this, the above worked fine for me but I had to add 'alarms' to permissions in the manifest file.