# Chrome extension: Update badge text every hour

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I just started messing around with chrome extensions and I need to perform some checks once every hour and update the badge text if necessary. I thought of using a `setInterval()` function in the background script which runs every 60 minutes to accomplish this. But I feel like this might not be the most efficient approach and there might be a better way to do this. Can someone suggest a method?

Secondly, I'd also like to know the lifetime of the background script. I read the docs but couldn't figure it out. Is it started when the browser is opened and stopped when the browser is closed? Thanks.

Comment: Use an automatically unloaded [event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) and alarms API: [Chrome Extension - Use javascript to run periodically, and log data permanently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36247160)

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I needed.